# Intuit Anywhere Login

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to pass the certification for the Intuit Anywhere. Here are the areas I need:

For SignIn WF 5.0 the Sign In With Intuit button is displayed even though the person is already signed into the App Center and therefore signed in with Intuit.

For SignIn WF 7.0 after disconnecting the company file from your application in the App Center when I logged into your application it still said the company file was connected to your application and allowed me to try to sync information.

For AppCenter 1.0 the Sign In With Intuit button is displayed even though the person is already signed into the App Center and therefore signed in with Intuit.

Using C# MVC, how do I tell my software that the user is logged into the app center? I logged into the app center and then I visited my app (cloudcartconnector.com.) I see no session variables or cookies I can use. Is there an API call to the app center I am missing?

Comment: Last I checked, "connector" type applications aren't even allowed on Intuit Anywhere. You're likely not even eligible to build for the platform. Our app did a similar thing and Intuit rejected it and wouldn't let us publish.

Comment: Keith, my app is similar to eCC from Webgility. They have a connector type app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My settings in the development area were wrong. I need to point to the right disconnect and open id urls:

[image]